# A stiffening chill-- is "stiffening" an adjective?

Tags: grammar

In the phrase "a stiffening chill", is "stiffening" an adjective?
The dictionary says that Stiffening is a present participle of the verb stiffen, or a noun.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is.  "Stiffening" is the present participle of the verb "to stiffen."  The present participle of nearly all verbs can be used as adjectives.

http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/ing-forms/

Comment: Like *walking stick*, *frying pan*, or *swimming shorts* - though I've noticed a tendency to drop the *...ing* so we now get *fry pan*, and *swim shorts*. How ridiculous!

Comment: You know, I've heard people say 'fry pan' and 'swim shorts', but until now, I never really registered it. Still, relating it to the question, a 'stiff wind' sounds like a strong or unyielding wind, while a 'stiffening wind' sounds like a bracing, cold wind. On that same note, maybe we'd do better to call a 'walking stick' a 'walk stick', for 'walking stick' has always conjured images in my mind of a stick getting up and walking about on its own, like Mickey Mouse's broom in Fantasia. (By the way, I would love to know how you manage to italicize words in comments as I haven't the option.)

Answer (score 4):

The word *stiffening* in this context is indeed an adjective derived from a verb.

My English-German dictionary tells me, it is an adjective. [Source](http://www.dict.cc/?s=stiffening)

> stiffening {adj}

In German, we call something like this a *pseudo-participle*.

Answer (score 2):

It is an ***attributive verb*** and more specifically a *deverbal adjective.*

*Attributive verb* is a verb that expresses the attribute of a noun.

A *deverbal adjective* is the one which is similar in the form as participles but behaves grammatically as adjectives.

*It was a very **intimidating** thought.*

Comment: Have you supporting references for your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the use is adjectival, and the form is a verb in present participle form. I would cautiously argue this might be a **gerundive**, oft thought not to exist in English. I think the question is whether stiffening describes whether the chill itself is becoming stiff (in which case it's merely a participle), or whether it indicates something else is (e.g. the person the chill hits). I think the latter is the case. Therefore, at least according to [this](http://www.newenglishreview.org/blog_direct_link.cfm?blog_id=2048), it might be a gerundive.

On the other hand the existence of such a part of speech in English appears controversial: *"There is no grammatical equivalent [to the Latin gerundive] in English, and the term is rarely used" (Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar, 2014).*; in that case I would suppose it is an adjective derived from the verb taking the form of the present participle.

Comment: I am not a language scholar, but I found this answer very informative. I'd say that the word in question is **functioning** as an adjective even if this _rare_ part of speech is the more technical answer.

Comment: If you are sailing in a stiffening breeze, the wind is getting stronger, and it is time to think about reefing. However, stiffening ribs in a structure make the structure stronger.

Comment: @BrianDrummond that's partly my fault. The question isn't *'a stiffening breeze'* (as I miscopied, and which means exactly what you say) but *'a stiffening chill'* (now edited to fix it). Does a *'a stiffening chill'* mean a chill that is intensifying? Or one that makes one stiff with cold? On reflection I think it's different from the chewing gum example ('gum which should be chewed') which is closer to a Latin gerundive.

Comment: If you can talk about a "stiff chill" - I think you can, as with a breeze - then surely either is a valid interpretation, resolved by context - e.g. "nightfall brought on a stiffening chill", suggests increasing cold as time passes.